# "I regretted not have told" - could it be ever correct?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, gerunds, infinitives

I have seen the following sentence:

> "I regretted not have told them the truth."

Could that be - in any context - ever correct? I would have expected something like "I regretted not having told them..."

Comment: It doesn't seem so... "I regretted not telling them the truth." is what I would use just because it is commonly said this way. "I regretted not have told them the truth" sounds like harshly broken English, but "I regretted not having told them..." sounds great.

Comment: "I regretted not to have told them the truth." also is probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

*Regret* takes an *-ing* clause (*I regret going out* like *I thought about going out*), not a bare infinitive clause (like "make": *He made me go out*), so no, it is not grammatical.

I know of no rule or logic which will tell you what kind of clauses a particular word can take.